# Client sent malformed Host header in AJAX call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, http-headers, bad-request

In an AJAX call, I'm sending textbox values as object to an ASP.NET page method as in sample below. The problem I'm facing is that when any of the textbox values contains `space` I get the error:

> Bad Request
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>
> Client sent malformed Host header

Although I'm using `data: JSON.stringify(obj)` the request fails almost 90% of the tries. But when all the textbox values are without `space` the request completes every time. Trying to figure it out but unable to catch the problem.

```
var obj = {};
obj.CapCode = $.trim($('#CapTextBox').val());
obj.Registered_Name = $.trim($('#Registered_NameTextBox').val()).replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
obj.eMail = $.trim($('#e_MailTextBox').val());
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Register.aspx/SaveRecord',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (resultData) {
        try {
            $("#User_modal").modal();
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert('ERROR:\n An error occurred while getting records. Try again.');
        }
    },
    error: function (x, e, m) {
        errorHandler(x, e, m, $("#btnSave"), false);
    },
});
```

The above code works without any problem on development system but on production gives this error

Comment: did you figure that one out?

Comment: No, I checked almost everything, front-end, back-end, server logs, page load etc. but no solution. I doubt it may be caused by some jquery/bootstrap plugin used in the template. Just for a test I removed all template css, js files and ajax and tried to save record to server which was successful.

Comment: I ended up replaceing `+` with space and the other way around server-side

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the solution to the problem but I cannot test it bcs I do not have enough rights on the server ;) http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModRewrite#Bewaretheencodingbug

> URL's that are requested via HTTP must be escaped (%xx-encoded) before they are sent, but Apache2's mod_rewrite unescapes path information which may generate invalid HTTP requests. In particular, spaces (which should be escaped as "%20") are not.
>
> ```
> # this cannot be on .htaccess (only on httpd.conf)
> RewriteMap escape int:escape 
>
> #and when writing RewriteRule:
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:6674/${escape:$1} [proxy]
> #(i.e., use ${escape:$1} instead of $1)
> ```